# Facebook Graph API - "Related Post" in status update

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

In the Facebook UI, you can hit "@" when you update your status and get a list of pages where your status update will be added as a Related Post on the page.

Is there a way to do the same in the Graph API? Assuming all authenticated, calling me/feed with a "message" parameter like this (using .NET Facebook SDK):

```
var client = new FacebookClient(ACCESS_TOKEN);
var parms = new Dictionary<string, object>();
parms.Add("message", "TEST fb SDK: @whatever");
client.Post("me/feed", parms);
```

The status update is posted, but the page doesn't doesn't get resolved as a Related Post.

If you GET a feed entry which has a Related Post created from the UI it's shown as a status update with the "to" parameter populated with the page. If you recreate that message as a POST in the API, the Related Post gets created, but:

- the Related Post shows on the Info tab of the page, not the Related Posts tab
- the status update doesn't have a link to the Related Post

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Someone has posted an undocumented way of [tagging users using Facebook Graph API](http://digitizor.com/2011/01/24/tag-user-facebook-graph/) that involves using a `@[{user_id}:1:{name}]` syntax, eg: `@[{4}:1:{Mark Zuckerberg}]`.  There is an open [request](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=13444) with Facebook for full documented support of this method.

Comment: Thanks for the response, [looks like Facebook have closed that loophole](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=12947) though.

Comment: Bummer. We will have to wait till they re-add support for it.